# Ruby: Way to convert method in model file to update data in a table's column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I created a method that is a day counter and shows the days remaining for the event. I have a `days` column in the table that I want to update with the days that it shows remaining in that method. 
I'm not sure how or where to make this change so that the data will automatically update the table. 
The code in my countdown method in my model file is:

```
  def event_days
    Integer(self.end_date - closer_to_end_date)
  end

  def closer_to_end_date
    if Date.today >= self.start_date
      Date.today
    elsif self.start_date >= Date.today
      self.start_date
    end
  end
```

I even tried to put `self.days` in place of `event_days` but it didn't update the days data in the table as I thought it would. Is this a change that I would have to make in the `days` migration file? If so, what should be added?

Comment: your conditional does not need an `elsif` because the result of the if condition implies the result of your `elsif`. In other words if today is not greater than or equal to `start_date` then `start_date` must be greater than today

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the object (instance of the model) in order to update the column in the table, for example:

```
self.days = Integer(self.end_date - closer_to_end_date)
self.save
```

Comment: So would I add that in the model file then call :self.days or just :days in after_initialize? or all that I need to do is add that in the controller in like the index?

Comment: @BelalKamara Where to put the code depends on how often and under which circumstances the `days` column is updated. If you are going to update it daily, then i would recommend avoiding the `days` column and just calculate the value on request, that is, calling `event_days` method. If you only need to set it once, then you can sen it in `after_initialize`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep u dont need function just days is negative or postive ..
Also try not write so confusing if elsif statements because all u needed else because elsif is oposite then if part.

Beside that dont see point saving that to database ..u can make calculations then u need display that data.

Also good tip is to read about callback functions at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html
Like it was mentioned before that u can set attribute calculated then model is intialized